# Error while adding emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, appium, automation-testing

This is the error message-
The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip' does not exist. [Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1]
Not sure what to do next.

Want to add emulator in android studio to write and run appium script on different virtual devices, but failing to do it.